# Removing lines from a polygon that has been reprojected to cross the antimeridian

Tags: qgis, polygon, antimeridian

I have a polygon file in qgis3.0 representing global tectonic plates. I have reprojected the original file in WGS84 (EPSG:4326) to PDC Mercator (EPSG:3832) using only the features that are needed.

Because each feature in the polygon crosses the antimeridian, some (selected) have lines cutting through them:

[image]

In the original file the two largest of these features have just one attribute entry, while the other has two but with identical values:[image]
[image: attribute table for the reprojected polygon]

There are probably a number of ways to remove these lines. So far I have tried Simplify and Polygons to Lines to manipulate the nodes but this just causes the outline to become deformed.

Screenshot of invalid geometries:
[image]

Comment: Try `Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Dissolve`, Uncheck `Dissolve All`, and select the `Code` field for dissolving.

Comment: This worked great for the two features that share attributes, however it hasn't dissolved the line between the larger two features.

Comment: Trying your issue with the data from https://github.com/fraxen/tectonicplates I get invalid geometries after reprojection of the pacific plate only to PDC Mercator.

Comment: Yes it is the same data. I have tried this myself and get the same results for both the pacific plate and the australian plate, I have added a screenshot of this. I'm not sure if there is a way to divide these features and then dissolve them. I also have the original data in  .dig format so it might be possible to create a new dataset which is not based on the wgs 84 but I don't know how this is done

Comment: It works for me if I run `Multipart to singlepart`  on the unprojected dataset, then reproject, then dissolve.

Answer (score 1):

As @AndreJ says: Multiparts to singleparts > reproject > dissolve